# Error when listing print queues from network server as impersonated user

Tags: service, printing, impersonation

I have been trying to set up a simple endpoint service that sits on a server, accepts a web request and then prints a job to a specific print queue on a specific server as a user, whose credentials are passed into the service.  This is for automated testing so the users that we are using have limited permissions so security is not a concern.

When I attempt this code without impersonation:

```
PrintServer ps = new PrintServer(@"\\" + serverName, PrintSystemDesiredAccess.EnumerateServer);
            response = "Created PrintServer object";
            foreach (PrintQueue pq in ps.GetPrintQueues())
            {
                response = response + "~@~" + pq.Name;
            }
```

It works properly and gives me a list of printers on the remote server, e.g:
Created PrintServer object~@~Sc-4 Pull Port~@~Microsoft XPS Document Writer

When I try it with impersonation I get this instead:
    System.Printing.PrintServerException: An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid.
at System.Printing.PrintServer.Initialize(String path, String[] propertiesFilter, PrinterDefaults printerDefaults)
   at System.Printing.PrintServer..ctor(String path, PrintSystemDesiredAccess desiredAccess)
   at PrintService.PrintService.ImpersonatedInstalledPrinterList(String serverName, String userName, String userPassword, String domain)

I have been unable to figure out, or find online, why it is throwing the above error.  I am using a valid domain account, and have even given the user I am using to test full permissions to the print queue on the server.  I get the same error when I attempt to print as an impersonated user, having no issue with sending a print job when I am not performing impersonation.

Thanks for any help you can offer,

Tsuki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with the code I was using, the problem was that I was using when I was using Impersonation, I was using SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL of Impersonation when I needed to be using Delegation.  Once I change that the error disappeared.